# Use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace variable number of characters with same number of constant characters

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to be able to replace a string of 4 or more digits with "#" characters for each digit, but leave smaller strings of digits as is.

Desired results:

```
'abc.1234.123456' -> 'abc.####.######'
'abc.12345.1'     -> 'abc.#####.1'
'abc.123.X'       -> 'abc.123.X'
'a4b.123456.8'    -> 'a4b.######.8'
```

I have tried something like this:

```
select regexp_replace(myString,
                      '([0-9]{4,})',
                      substr('##############',1,length('\1'))) from dual
```

but the \1 back-reference is just treated as a regular character string and I get results like this:

```
'abc.1234.123456' -> 'abc.##.##'
'abc.12345.1'     -> 'abc.##.1'
'abc.123.X'       -> 'abc.123.X'
'a4b.123456.8'    -> 'a4b.##.8'
```

...just two "#" characters because the length of '\1' is 2.

Comment: hmm, what's the use of `length('\1')` ?

Comment: My thought was that it might give me the length of the back reference, ([0-9]{4}), but it only gave me the length of '\1' which is always 2.  Gordon's solution did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `regexp_substr()` as the argument.

```
select regexp_replace(myString,
                      '([0-9]{4,})',
                      substr('###########', 1, length(regexp_substr(myString, '([0-9]{4,})', 1)))
                     )
from (select 'abc.12345.1' as mystring from dual) x;
```

Comment: This solution does work for the data I presented, but if there is more than one string of 4 or more digits in myString it doesn't quite work.  For example 'abc.12345567.1234' becomes 'abc.########.########' rather than the desired 'abc.########.####'

Comment: Are your strings always in those three parts?

Comment: No, there can be several parts.  They are file names essentially, so the numeric characters could be intermixed with alpha characters or separated with underscores, dashes, periods, etc.  My end goal is to get a list of unique file names, without considering the numeric portion of the file -- date/time stamps of various lengths and formats, etc.  However it would still be good to have the proper number of # so I can have at least a better sense of the format of the file name.

Comment: @JohnE . . . My suggestion would be repeated applications of `regexp_replace()` with one series at a time.  I still haven't thought of a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like so, with `LENGTH('\1\1')` rather than `LENGTH('\1')`

```
                  SELECT regexp_replace('a4b.1234567.8'  ,
                  '([0-9]{4,})',
                  substr('######',1,LENGTH('\1\1'))) FROM dual;
```

yields :

```
a4b.####.8
```

Comment: That replaces every string of digits with 4 "#" characters.  I wanted a "#" for each digit in any string of digits that are 4 in length or longer.